# Listen when something changes and update it to database

Tags: java, mongodb, task, future, morphia

So I'm developing a software that uses mongodb/morphia and I need a way to listen that object to check when a certain value changes to update it in the database instead of doing it manually.

What's the best way to do it? Observer Pattern?

So I have 3 classes: User(super class), GlobalPlayer and my Main.
I know I need to use an Observer Pattern but I'm having questions while implementing.

User Class:
[image: User Class]

GlobalPlayer Class:
[image: GlobalPlayer Class]

Main Class:
[image]

As you can see on my main class I'm updating my GlobalPlayer every 5 seconds even if that same don't have any new update, so how can I implement the observer pattern into this?

Comment: I would suggest changing your title to something more specific and adding more information in your question body.

Comment: @clabe45 Sure, check if it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a dirty flag.**

With an observer pattern you can track each change. But do you really want to save each user every time a little change is done? Probably not, so when using an observer you might also want to build something that prevents too high a database load by delaying writes. Also, I always try to keep my *Dataobjects* simple, with loose connections, as this reduces complexity. Thus my guess is that an observer pattern is overkill and makes it more complicated than needed. Just using a dirty bit and a scheduled task to save each user periodically. Not much load and only minor data loss in case of a system crash.

```
public class User {

  @Transient
  boolean dirty;

  private void markDirty() {
    dirty = true;
  }

  public void isDirty {
    return dirty();
  }
```

Each setter, should first call the *markDirty()* method. Like this:

```
public void addCoins(long coins) {
  markDirty();
  this.coins += coins;
}
```

And in Global we only save a user when he/she/it/other is dirty:

```
if (gp.isDirty()) {
  getPlayerManager().update(gp);
}
```

An even better design would move the `if(gp.isDirty())` to the `update` of the PlayerManager class, as it should be the responsibility of the Playermanager when to save.

Answer (score 0):

*<strike>As jjohns pointed out, you can use [`Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)s and [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)s</strike>*

#### Edit

He probably didn't mean that. **As of Java 9, this observer pattern is deprecated.**
One alternative is to declare your own event that subclasses [`EventObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html):

```
class UserChangeEvent extends EventObject {
    private String actionCommand;  // additional property for more control
    public UserChangeEvent(Object source, String actionCommand) {
        super(source);
        this.actionCommand = actionCommand;
    }
    public String getActionCommand() { return actionCommand; }
}
```

Then, declare an interface that will handle the events (`onUserChange(UserChangeEvent)` will be the "callback" method):

```
interface UserChangeListener {
    /**
     * Fired when any user property changes
     * @param event
     */
    public void onUserChange(UserChangeEvent event);
}
```

Here's a sample `User` class:

```
class User {
    private List<UserChangeListener> changeListeners = new ArrayList<UserChangeListener>();
    private String username;
    private String email;
    
    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
    /**
     * Registers a UserChangeListener instance that will be notified when any setter is called
     * @param listener the new event listener
     */
    public void addUserChangeListener(UserChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.add(listener);
    }
    public String getUsername() { 
        return username; 
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) { 
        this.username = username;  // actually set the username
        UserChangeEvent event = new UserChangeEvent(this, "username");  // a new instance of our custom user change event
        // fire user change event for all event listeners
        for (UserChangeListener listener:changeListeners) {
            listener.onUserChange(event);
        }
    }
    public String getEmail() { 
        return email; 
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) { 
        this.email = email; 
        UserChangeEvent event = new UserChangeEvent(this, "email");
        for (UserChangeListener listener:changeListeners) {
            listener.onUserChange(event);
        }
    }   
}
```

Here's a simple implementation of `User`, `UserChangeEvent`, and `UserChangeListener`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User hworld1234 = new User("hworld1234", "hworld@example.com");
        hworld1234.addUserChangeListener(new UserChangeListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onUserChange(UserChangeEvent event) {
                String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();  // what we gave our custom event in the setters
                if ("username".equals(actionCommand)) {
                    System.out.println("username has been changed to '" + hworld1234.getUsername() + "'");
                } else if ("email".equals(actionCommand)) {
                    System.out.println("email has been changed to '" + hworld1234.getEmail() + "'");
                }
            }
        });
        hworld1234.setEmail("hworld@gmail.com");  // prints "email has been changed to 'hworld@gmail.com'"

    }   
}
```

If you prefer, another way of doing this is to declare an onXXXChange for each property to be "bound" and forget the `actionCommand` property; although, if you even have more than one method in an interface, you should probably turn it into an adapter.

Comment: This is a very poorly implemented version of the observable/observer pattern.

Comment: @jjones How so? How can I improve?

Comment: Here's a UML class and sequence diagram of a simple implementation: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/W3sDesign_Observer_Design_Pattern_UML.jpg

Comment: Your class is limited to a single effect, and requires knowledge of how to perform that effect.

Comment: @jjones Im gonna take a look of that observer pattern, thanks :D

Comment: @clabe45 well i tried that way but for some reason my user's data dont update, im performing the update to db but nothing changes

Comment: What does your `updateDB` (or whatever you named it) look like?